# Material-ui - The style in local and production is different

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, material-ui

I have had a big problem for some time now.
I'm working on ReactJS with Material-UI, I have a library (which I build with webpack) and then use it on my projects.
The problem is that in local or on StoryBook, the style renders perfectly well. But when the library is built and added to my project via my package.json my style does not apply.

I override the style directly on my css file and I don't go through withStyle/useStyle/makeStyle. I know this is the right way to do it but unfortunately the project was already like that when I got it back

On StoryBook:

[image]

And prod:
[image]

If anyone has a solution or has seen this somewhere?

Thanks